# How can I sort my non-gmail emails?

Tags: email, 4.4-kitkat, stock-email-app

I would like to sort my non-gmail emails in a different order (e.g. from oldest to newest, to read the emails in chronological order). How can I do it in KitKat? I was really easy on my old HTC Desire :(

Comment: Which email app is this? The stock email app?

Comment: @geffchang, yes, the stock email app (but not the gmail one).

Comment: Hmm, I've not found any way to sort via Email app. You mention non-Gmail, though. Do you have any GMail accounts on the Email app? Are they sortable? / Personally, I use Kaiten app with all my GMail accounts, and I can sort by Date, Arrival, Subject, Sender, Star, Read/undread, and Attachments.